# NSString loop characters and NSDictionary objectForKey

Tags: nsstring, nsdictionary

I have a NSString @"Test" and NSDictionary @"T" -> @"String1" | @"e" -> @"String2" | @"s" -> @"String3"

I would like to loop through all characters of the string and for each character perform NSDictionary objectForKey method.

The result should be a NSString @"String1 String2 String 3 String 1"

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

```
    NSString       *str    = @"test!";
    NSDictionary   *dict   = @{@"t":@"T",@"e":@"E",@"s":@"S"};
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSUInteger i=0, n=str.length;  i<n;  i++) {
        NSString *key = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
        id value = dict[key];
        [result addObject:(value != nil)? value : @"?"];
    }
```